# Navigating between Fragments in Espresso UI test

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-navigation, dagger-hilt

I am trying to write a UI test with Espresso that runs across multiple Fragments. They share a viewModel injected via `by activityViewModels()`.
I am using Android Navigation component, Dagger Hilt injection and a mocked NavController like this:

```
val navController = Mockito.mock(NavController::class.java)
launchFragmentInHiltContainer<AddRecipeFragment1> {
    Navigation.setViewNavController(requireView(), navController)
}
// Here I need to initialize some data in viewModel...
```

After this I want to navigate to another Fragment that I actually want to test, but neither pressing a button that calls the navigation nor calling `navController.navigate(AddRecipeFragment1Directions.toAddRecipeFragment2())` works for me.

An approach using `launchFragmentInHiltContainer<AddRecipeFragment>...` will restart the whole application and drop the viewModel.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found a workaround doing this:

```
private lateinit var viewModel: AddRecipeViewModel

@Before
fun beforeEach() {
    ...

    navController = Mockito.mock(NavController::class.java)
    launchFragmentInHiltContainer<AddRecipeFragment2> {
        val viewModelTemp: AddRecipeViewModel by activityViewModels()
        viewModel = viewModelTemp
        Navigation.setViewNavController(requireView(), navController)
    }
}
```

This way I can at least access the delegated ViewModel directly in my tests.